# Check TextBoxes in Userform to make sure that they are integers

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to check my `Userform` when a command button is clicked to ensure that all the values entered in textboxes are `integers`.  However, right now it's popping up with the message box even if I enter an `integer` value (i.e. 1 for all the textboxes).

Here's my code right now:

```
'Store inputs when clicking Continue
Private Sub Continue1_Click()

    'Define variables
    Dim Ctl As Control

    For Each Ctl In CategoriesForm.Controls
        If TypeName(Ctl) = "TextBox" Then
            If IsNumeric(Ctl.Value) = True Then
                If Int(Ctl.Value) <> Ctl.Value Then
                    MsgBox ("All inputs need to be integers for calculations to work.  Please check the values."), vbCritical, "Error: Not All Inputs are Integers"
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox ("All inputs need to be integers for calculations to work.  Please check the values."), vbCritical, "Error: Not All Inputs are Integers"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next

    NumberClamps = Number_Clamps.Value
    NumberBrackets = Number_Brackets.Value
    NumberWashers = Number_Washers.Value
    NumberScrews = Number_Screws.Value
    NumberNuts = Number_Nuts.Value
    NumberUNuts = Number_UNuts.Value
    NumberRivets = Number_Rivets.Value
    NumberStuds = Number_Studs.Value
    Unload CategoriesForm

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Uh. Both message box is the same??

Comment: I agree with @findwindow, which MsgBox is displaying? I'd suggest stepping through in the debugger to check the values to see where the logic is taking you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a sub that only allows user to enter numeric keys

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Select Case KeyAscii
      Case vbKey0 To vbKey9
      Case Else
        KeyAscii = 0
        Beep
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Uh I didn't ask the question so can't mark as answered but +1

Comment: Oh that's awesome thanks!  Do I need to put a separate sub for each text box?

Comment: yes. You can also do it in the original SUB with something like ISNUMERIC, however I just like preventing the user from entering non acceptable characters in the first place. You should look up the vbKeys vlaues as well as the ascii values as well.

Comment: I was able to do it with your code and something else I found on class modules.  I'll edit my answer to show what I did.

Comment: ? what did you do?

Comment: Ah super cool. Add it to you original post so future people can copy paste. It is worth noting that this is only useful when all textboxes in the module need to be integers. will be messy if some need non numeric characters

Comment: Yeah I added an answer right below.  It definitely works.  Not exactly sure how as it's a little bit above my level :P.

Answer (score 0):

In conjunction with Doug Coats Solution

Create Class Module called "CTextboxes"

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents TextGroup As MSForms.TextBox


'Sub to allow users to only enter integer values
Private Sub TextGroup_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)

Select Case KeyAscii
  Case vbKey0 To vbKey9
  Case Else
    KeyAscii = 0
    Beep
    MsgBox ("All inputs need to be integers for calculations to work.  Please check the values."), vbCritical, "Error: All Inputs must be Integers"
End Select

End Sub
```

Put this code in the UserForm code module for when the USerForm initializes

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Stop user from entering non-integer values
Dim Ctl As MSForms.Control
Dim i As Long

i = 1

For Each Ctl In Me.Controls

    If TypeName(Ctl) = "TextBox" Then
        ReDim Preserve TextBoxes(1 To i)
        Set TextBoxes(i).TextGroup = Ctl
        i = i + 1
    End If

Next Ctl

End Sub
```

Finally define this variable at the top of the UserForm Code

```
Option Explicit

Dim TextBoxes() As New CTextboxes
```